# I am adding constructor on react native but it shows error

Tags: react-native

I am adding this constructor:

```
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      showPass: true,
      press: false
    }
  }
```

on react native but it shows this error:

```
er: Unexpected token, expected";"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Constructor on works in class

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      showPass: true,
      press: false
    }
  }
  render() {
      return <h1>Class component.</h1>;
  }
}
```